# Group by on multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to Oracle SQL and am still learning, I'm trying to work out what `GROUP BY` I need to use.

The subquery works by itself:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')          "DTTM"  
                 , CASE_NBR
                 , COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_1, LPN.TC_ASN_ID)             "REF_FIELD_1"
                 , COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_2, LPN.ASN_ID || LPN.ITEM_ID) "REF_FIELD_2"
            FROM PIX_TRAN PT, LPN
            WHERE ( ( PT.TRAN_TYPE = '300'
                      AND PT.TRAN_CODE = '01'
                      AND PT.ACTN_CODE = '20' )
                    OR ( PT.TRAN_TYPE = '300'
                         AND PT.TRAN_CODE = '04'
                         AND PT.ACTN_CODE = '21' ) )
                  AND SUBSTR(COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_1, LPN.TC_ASN_ID), 1, INSTR(COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_1, LPN.TC_ASN_ID), '_', 1)) != 'Return_'
                  AND PT.CASE_NBR = LPN.TC_LPN_ID (+)
                  AND PT.WHSE = 'DCV'
                  AND TRUNC(CREATE_DATE_TIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

But when I try to add it as a subquery with a `GROUP BY`, I can't seem to work out what the correct `GROUP BY` should be?

```
SELECT 'PO Lines/LPNs Putaway'     AS "FACILITY_ACTIVITY"
     , TRUNC DTTM     AS "CREATED"
     , COUNT(DISTINCT REF_FIELD_1 || REF_FIELD_2)|| '/'|| COUNT(DISTINCT CASE_NBR) "Total"
FROM (      
            SELECT TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')          "DTTM"  
                 , CASE_NBR
                 , COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_1, LPN.TC_ASN_ID)             "REF_FIELD_1"
                 , COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_2, LPN.ASN_ID || LPN.ITEM_ID) "REF_FIELD_2"
            FROM PIX_TRAN PT, LPN
            WHERE ( ( PT.TRAN_TYPE = '300'
                      AND PT.TRAN_CODE = '01'
                      AND PT.ACTN_CODE = '20' )
                    OR ( PT.TRAN_TYPE = '300'
                         AND PT.TRAN_CODE = '04'
                         AND PT.ACTN_CODE = '21' ) )
                  AND SUBSTR(COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_1, LPN.TC_ASN_ID), 1, INSTR(COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_1, LPN.TC_ASN_ID), '_', 1)) != 'Return_'
                  AND PT.CASE_NBR = LPN.TC_LPN_ID (+)
                  AND PT.WHSE = 'DCV'
                  AND TRUNC(CREATE_DATE_TIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
    )
GROUP BY TRUNC(DTTM);
```

I've tried the following `GROUP BY`'s

```
GROUP BY TRUNC(DTTM)
```

> ERROR - "FROM Keyword not found  where expected"

```
GROUP BY TRUNC(TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
```

with changing the select clause to

```
TRUNC(TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) AS "CREATED"
```

> ERROR - "CREATE_DATE_TIME" invalid identifier

```
GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATE_DATE_TIME)
```

with changing the select clause to

```
TRUNC(CREATE_DATE_TIME) AS "CREATED"
```

> ERROR - "CREATE_DATE_TIME" invalid identifier

Can someone please point out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I formatted your queries which makes it easy to see the issue

Original

```
SELECT
    to_char(create_date_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY')            "DTTM",
    case_nbr,
    coalesce(pt.ref_field_1, lpn.tc_asn_id)             "REF_FIELD_1",
    coalesce(pt.ref_field_2, lpn.asn_id || lpn.item_id) "REF_FIELD_2"
FROM
    pix_tran pt,
    lpn
WHERE
    ( ( pt.tran_type = '300'
        AND pt.tran_code = '01'
        AND pt.actn_code = '20' )
      OR ( pt.tran_type = '300'
           AND pt.tran_code = '04'
           AND pt.actn_code = '21' ) )
    AND substr(coalesce(pt.ref_field_1, lpn.tc_asn_id),
               1,
               instr(coalesce(pt.ref_field_1, lpn.tc_asn_id),
                     '',
                     1)) != 'Return'
    AND pt.case_nbr = lpn.tc_lpn_id (+)
    AND pt.whse = 'DCV'
    AND trunc(create_date_time) = trunc(sysdate)
```

Inline view

```
select 'PO Lines/LPNs Putaway' as "FACILITY_ACTIVITY",
       trunc dttm AS "CREATED" , COUNT(DISTINCT REF_FIELD_1 || REF_FIELD_2)|| '/'|| COUNT(DISTINCT CASE_NBR) "Total" FROM
(
  select to_char(
    create_date_time,
    'DD-MON-YYYY'
  ) "DTTM",
         case_nbr,
         coalesce(
           pt.ref_field_1,
           lpn.tc_asn_id
         ) "REF_FIELD_1",
         coalesce(
           pt.ref_field_2,
           lpn.asn_id || lpn.item_id
         ) "REF_FIELD_2"
    from pix_tran pt,
         lpn
   where ( ( pt.tran_type = '300'
     and pt.tran_code = '01'
     and pt.actn_code = '20' )
      or ( pt.tran_type = '300'
     and pt.tran_code = '04'
     and pt.actn_code = '21' ) )
     and substr(
                 coalesce(
                         pt.ref_field_1,
                         lpn.tc_asn_id
                 ),
                 1,
                 instr(
                      coalesce(
                              pt.ref_field_1,
                              lpn.tc_asn_id
                      ),
                      '',
                      1
                 )
           ) != 'Return'
     and pt.case_nbr = lpn.tc_lpn_id (+)
     and pt.whse = 'DCV'
     and trunc(create_date_time) = trunc(sysdate)
)
 group by trunc(dttm);
```

You are missing the brackets on your TRUNC, and since your DTTM is a string, the use of trunc at all is probably not appropriate.

I would move the TRUNC inside the subquery (it will reduce the datetime to a date) and then just group by DTTM

Comment: so changing my outer query to just select DTTM as CREATED for the 2nd column, then GROUP BY DTTM has given results. thats with just removing the TRUNC in the select/group by

FACILITY_ACTIVITY -  PO Lines/LPNs Putaway          
CREATED -  14-FEB-2023        
TOTAL - 1308/1522